# Share a multi-type map between users

Tags: c++, enums, memoization

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759124/containers-for-different-signature-functions) and [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/126395/c-multi-function-memoizator-and-multi-type-container) question I talked about (and proposed a solution) to write a multi-function memoizator.

This is my solution:

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
function<ReturnType(Args...)> memoize(function<ReturnType(Args...)> func)
{
    return ([=](Args... args) mutable {
        static map<tuple<Args...>, ReturnType> cache;
        tuple<Args...> t(args...);
        auto result = cache.insert(make_pair(t, ReturnType{}));
        if (result.second) {
            // insertion succeeded so the value wasn't cached already
            result.first->second = func(args...);
        }
        return result.first->second;
    });
}

struct MultiMemoizator
{
    map<string, boost::any> multiCache;
    template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
    void addFunction(string name, function < ReturnType(Args...)> func) {
        function < ReturnType(Args...)> cachedFunc = memoize(func);
        boost::any anyCachedFunc = cachedFunc;
        auto result = multiCache.insert(pair<string, boost::any>(name,anyCachedFunc));
        if (!result.second)
            cout << "ERROR: key " + name + " was already inserted" << endl;
    }
    template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
    ReturnType callFunction(string name, Args... args) {
        auto it = multiCache.find(name);
        if (it == multiCache.end())
            throw KeyNotFound(name);
        boost::any anyCachedFunc = it->second;
        function < ReturnType(Args...)> cachedFunc = boost::any_cast<function<ReturnType(Args...)>> (anyCachedFunc);
        return cachedFunc(args...);
    }
};
```

And this is a possible main:

```
int main()
{
    function<int(int)> intFun = [](int i) {return ++i; };
    function<string(string)> stringFun = [](string s) {
        return "Hello "+s;
    };
    MultiMemoizator mem;
    mem.addFunction("intFun",intFun);
    mem.addFunction("stringFun", stringFun);
    try
    {
        cout << mem.callFunction<int, int>("intFun", 1)<<endl;//print 2
        cout << mem.callFunction<string, string>("stringFun", " World!") << endl;//print Hello World!
        cout << mem.callFunction<string, string>("TrumpIsADickHead", " World!") << endl;//KeyNotFound thrown
    }
    catch (boost::bad_any_cast e)
    {
        cout << "Bad function calling: "<<e.what()<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
    catch (KeyNotFound e) 
    {
        cout << e.what()<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

To make it type safe at compile time, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36773865/4480180) answer the author suggest to use a (for example) a `Key<int(int)>`. The problem with this solution is that two function with same signature cannot be inserted. So, as proposed in of the comments in [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/126452/66373) answer, we could enum each function to uniquely identify each function. Or we could add this enumeration inside the `struct Key` so we could preserve the type safety and uniquely identify each function.

**THE PROBLEM:**

I want to expand this solution so it can be used by different users. So if `user1` defines for example some function `int foo(int x)` and memoize it in `multiCache`, it can write `multiCache` on file and `user2` can use it for the same `int foo(int x)` (obviously it's responsability of `user2` that `foo` is the same function used by `user1`).

The problem of the previous solution is that the `enum` defined by `user1` for `foo` could not match by the one defined by `user2` for the same function.

**A POSSIBLE SOLUTION:**

What about if instead of `enum` we could define a "probably unique" key for each function, like `SHA(functionName)`? Then we could write on file both `multiCache` object and a text file where we write `(functionName,SHA(functioName))` and expose them to `user2`? Could be inefficient or unsafe (apart from the low probability of same sha code)?

Comment: please post all relevant information in your question. Links can aid for additional information, but all essential should be included in the question

Comment: I added the code of my solution