# c++ : Multiple move on the same object and perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, move, perfect-forwarding

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759124/containers-for-different-signature-functions) question I talked about how to create a multi-function memoizator. In one of the answers, it was suggested to implement perfect forwarding, so passing the arguments to desired function will result inexpensive, like this:

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
    ReturnType callFunction(MemFunc<ReturnType, Args...> memFunc, Args&& ... args) //rvalue reference of args
    {
        auto it = multiCache.find(memFunc.name);
        if (it == multiCache.end())
            throw KeyNotFound(memFunc.name);
        boost::any anyCachedFunc = it->second;
        function < ReturnType(Args...)> cachedFunc = boost::any_cast<function<ReturnType(Args...)>> (anyCachedFunc);
        return cachedFunc(forward<Args> (args) ...);//perfect forwarding
    }
```

I'm not an expert of move semantic and perfect forwarding, but from what I've understood we need to pass an rvalue when we call `callFunction`.

So the first `callFunction` calling is illegal, while the second one is:

```
typedef vector<double> vecD;
MultiMemoizator mem;
//lambda function that returns the sorted vector (just for fun)
function<vecD(vecD)> sort_vec = [](vecD vec) {
    sort(vec.begin(),vec.end());
    return vec;
};
vector<vecD> vec;
// here fill vec...
mem.callFunction<double, double>(sortFunc, vec); //error! vec is an lvalue
mem.callFunction<double, double>(sortFunc, move(vec));//OK: move(vec) return an rvalue of the lvalue (vec)
```

The problem is that in this application, `callFunction` is supposed to be called several times on the same object, which is not supposed to happen once we call `move` on our object.

So for example:

```
mem.callFunction<double, double>(sortFunc, move(vec));//First time: sorting will take A LONG time because vec is not memoized
//now is not safe to use vec anymore...but it's memoized for sortFunc
mem.callFunction<double, double>(sortFunc, move(vec));//computed quickly because of memoization, but unsafe because of first move!
```

So from what I can understand I have to make a choice:

- Give up on perfect forwarding implementing `callFunction(MemFunc<ReturnType, Args...> memFunc, Args ... args)` (or `Args & ... args`) , but introducing an expensive copy when we call `cachedFunc(args)`
- Keep the efficient perfect forwarding, but introduce possible unexpected behaviour on multiple `move` on the same object

Obviously the second choice is not acceptable, so how can I avoid the first one?

**A POSSIBLE SOLUTION:**

The solution posted above is too much restrictive for the user: what if he wants, for some reason, to use `vec` again? So a possible solution could be to overload `callFunction` so it accept *both* solutions:

```
//rvalue reference/move/perfect forwarding implementation
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
    ReturnType callFunction(MemFunc<ReturnType, Args...> memFunc, Args&& ... args) {
...
        return cachedFunc(forward<Args> (args) ...);//perfect forwarding
}

//lvalue reference/no perfect forwarding implementation
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
    ReturnType callFunction(MemFunc<ReturnType, Args...> memFunc, Args& ... args) {
...
        return cachedFunc(args);//expensive!
}
```

This solution has some disadvantage or could lead to some problem?

Comment: So... if an object is unique and cannot be duplicated, then it's not clear how you can memoize a call for which it is an argument, since you would need to both keep a copy in the cache *and* use another copy for the actual call. (And move semantics are about treating objects as though they were unique.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't get one point: when did I say that I cannot duplicate the object? It could be for sure really time expensive, but there is no constraint to not do it.

Comment: It was just a general design comment regarding memoization and move semantics. Move semantics are *conceptually* about uniqueness, so you need to think about how you want to organize your data. In the sorting example, without memoization you can effectively sort a vector in-place. With memoization, you throw away the input vector and make a copy of the cached result,

Comment: Also, there's nothing "unsafe" anywhere. "Unsafe" doesn't really mean anything. You should *never* read an object that was moved-from, ever.

Comment: By unsafe I mean that could lead to "unexpected behavior", which is why (from what I know) you should **never** read a moved-from object.

Comment: I don't quite understand the reasoning in your "possible solution". Surely if the user wants to keep the vector, they would simply not move it?

Comment: As I said, `mem.callFunction<double, double>(sortFunc, vec); ` generates an error with `ReturnType callFunction(MemFunc<ReturnType, Args...> memFunc, Args&& ... args)` since `vec` is an lvalue (while callFunction expects and rvalue) and so will generate a `You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference` compile time error